# Is it possible for an app to POST to a web browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Is it possible for a mobile app (iOS and Android) at the click of a "Share" or "Upload" button, to have a file POSTed to a URL?

If it is possible, does it involve any additional permissions for the application?

Comment: Please comment a downvote!

Comment: @Seraphim - Seriously... I hate that about StackOverflow.  People willing to throw out down votes but not feedback on why it's a bad question.

Comment: even if... I expect a better questions from a 7k rep. user ;) But I think it's a legitimate question for Android iOS newbies

Comment: @Seraphim - This was a poor question I'll admit.  Felt like an idiot once I saw Zabri's post.  Though in my defense I have very little Android/iOS experience.

Comment: :) ...as I thought. So, welcome! :) (I remember I made a lot of no-sense questions in the first month. But your has sense, I suppose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

The permission you need would be `INTERNET`. (Well, duh.)